# How should I get the absolute URL in CsQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, csquery

I'm trying to get the absolute URI of each anchor tag on a Wikipedia page. I think the .href property should give the absolute URI but when I'm trying it in CsQuery I'm finding that it still gives me the relative URI. How should I get the absolute URI?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama";
        var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl(url);
        var selected = dom["div#mw-content-text a"];
        foreach (var a in selected)
            Console.WriteLine(a["href"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CsQuery shows you whatever exists in HTML page...

You can simply do that:

```
 string domain = "https://en.wikipedia.org";

 var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl(url);

 List<string> urls = new List<string>();

 dom["a[href]"].Each(dom=>{
    string url = dom.GetAttribute("href");
    if(!url.StartsWith("https"))
       url = domain + url;

    urls.Add(url);
 });
```

});

Comment: Yes. I understand you can always use "domain + url" to give the absolute URI. But for each anchor text, its href attribute in fact should provide the absolute URI if you check it in Chrome Developer Tools. Is there a similar approach in CsQuery?

Comment: Chrome knows the context of the page so it can build the full URL. CsQuery doesn't know anything about where a page is located in a heirachy, it's just markup. So you will need to do something like this.